# create auto increment integer field in django

Tags: django

i want to create auto increment integer field. I want to create an ID for each user.
I am a beginner and please explain completely and clearly :)
I want to automatically assign an ID to each user.

my Model:

```
from django.db import models
class User_account(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    marital_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bio = models.CharField(default='' ,max_length=200)


def __str__(self):
    return f"(@{self.username}) {self.fullname}"

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.username = self.username.lower()
    self.email = self.email.lower()
    return super(User_account, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

my View:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import User_account

def profile(request, username):
    users = User_account.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        if username == user.username:
            return render(request, 'account_app/profile.html', context={"user_info":user})

def users_list(request):
    users = User_account.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'account_app/users_list.html', context={"user_info":users})
```

Comment: You don't need to create id, It creates automatically in Django. Just use this tag in templates {{ users.id }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify a field with [**`primary_key=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#primary-key), this means that Django will *automatically* add a field to your model named `id`.

If you do not change the [**`DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD), or set the [**`default_auto_field`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.default_auto_field) of the `AppConfig` of your app, it will use an [**`AutoField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) which is an `IntegerField` that will automatically add a value. You thus can access this with `myuser.id` or `myuser.pk`.

Please do *not* use loops to filter on the `username`, this will result in *linear search* in the Django/Python layer. It is better to filter the database with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User_account, username=username)
    return render(request, 'account_app/profile.html', context={'user_info': user})
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly about the auto-increment integer field? I said I was a beginner.

Comment: @aprogrammer: it is automatically added to your `User_account`, since you did not specify a field with `primary_key=True`.

Comment: Does linear search on the Django / Python layer cause an error in my application or slow down speed the display of results?

Comment: @aprogrammer: it will result in a massive amount of data from the database to the application layer, and thus will slow down the application and database.

Comment: Even if I use the for loop in the html file{%for user in users%}, do I still have such a problem?
My next question is, does the while loop also slow down?